# Multiple Threads Accessing the socket read causing jvm OutOfMemory Issue

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets, memory-leaks, out-of-memory

Assume we have the socket client , which is doing read and write . There is a two threads doing the operation send and receive (request sender / response receiver). These threads are running the Junit test cases one by one (Like some stress test , simple enquiry) . For my case  i am running the client ,which will establish the socket communication in between DB end and its own side.  In this logic , request sender threads sends the request to DB end (writes the requests in to socket) , the receiver threads receives the response by reading the socket (read the response from the socket) . The actual problem randomly appears. Assume if request sender threads sends the request , response receiver not yet received the response from other end of the request which sent. During that time if any other Testcases (I mean request threads) which starts (after a particular timeout period ,if there is no response from DB end) to send their requests  and do the execution means, the response receiver thread having the logic of

```
byte[] ofsRes = new byte[size];
```

This part will receive the jVm Out of memory error occurs. i suspect the simultaneous read of response receiver threads causing this issue, allocating more size of byte object in heap.

reading data from socket

```
int size = dataInputStream.readInt();
```

Can you please help anyone to solve this issue out of memory error / may be concurrency of threads , even i used synchronized .but no use .Let me know if you need anything.

```
private static class ResponseReceiver implements Runnable {

        private InputStream _in;
        private List<String> _responses = new ArrayList<String>();
        private int _expectedCount;
        private volatile boolean _finished = false;

        public ResponseReceiver(InputStream in, int expectedCount) {
            _in = in;
            _expectedCount = expectedCount;
        }

        public List<String> getResponses() {
            return _responses;
        }

        public void run() {
            DataInputStream dataInputStream = new DataInputStream(_in);
            try {
                while (true) {
                    _logger.info("_responses.size() >= _expectedCount : -> " + (_responses.size() >= _expectedCount) +
                            " : " + "_responses.size() -> " + _responses.size() + " : " + "_expectedCount -> " + _expectedCount);
                    if (_responses.size() >= _expectedCount) {
                        _finished = true;
                        return;
                    }
                    int size = dataInputStream.readInt();
                    _logger.info("size captured : " + size);
                    if (size > 0) {
                        int readSize = 0;
                        _logger.info( " ofsRes Creating with this size : " + size);
                        **byte[] ofsRes = new byte[size];**
                        while (size > 0) {
                            _logger.info( " Buffer Creating with this size : " + size);
                            byte[] buffer = new byte[size];
                            int bufferSize = _in.read(buffer);
                            _logger.info( " Reading data created Buffer Size : " + bufferSize);
                            System.arraycopy(buffer, 0, ofsRes, readSize,
                                    bufferSize);
                            readSize += bufferSize;
                            _logger.info( " readSize (readSize += bufferSize): " + readSize);
                            size -= bufferSize;
                            _logger.info( " size (size -= bufferSize): " + size);
                        }
                        _responses.add(new String(ofsRes));
                        _logger.info("ofsRes added..");
                    }
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                throw new RuntimeException("Error reading data from socket: "
                        + e.getMessage());
            }
        }
    }
```

The trace of execution order:

---

May 27, 2013 11:45:13 AM com.xxx.tocf.test.socket.SocketClient$ResponseReceiver run
INFO: _responses.size() >= _expectedCount : -> false : _responses.size() -> 905 : _expectedCount -> 1000
May 27, 2013 11:45:13 AM com.xxx.tocf.test.socket.SocketClient$ResponseReceiver run
INFO: size captured : 1529
May 27, 2013 11:45:13 AM com.xxx.tocf.test.socket.SocketClient$ResponseReceiver run
INFO:  ofsRes Creating with this size : 1529
May 27, 2013 11:45:13 AM com.xxx.tocf.test.socket.SocketClient$ResponseReceiver run
INFO:  Buffer Creating with this size : 1529
May 27, 2013 11:45:13 AM com.xxx.tocf.test.socket.SocketClient$ResponseReceiver run
INFO:  Reading data created Buffer Size : 1529
May 27, 2013 11:45:13 AM com.xxx.tocf.test.socket.SocketClient$ResponseReceiver run
INFO:  readSize (readSize += bufferSize): 1529
May 27, 2013 11:45:13 AM com.xxx.tocf.test.socket.SocketClient$ResponseReceiver run
INFO:  size (size -= bufferSize): 0
May 27, 2013 11:45:13 AM com.xxx.tocf.test.socket.SocketClient$ResponseReceiver run
INFO: ofsRes added..
May 27, 2013 11:45:13 AM com.xxx.tocf.test.socket.SocketClient$ResponseReceiver run
**INFO: _responses.size() >= _expectedCount : -> false : _responses.size() -> 906** : _expectedCount -> 1000

***Assume a test case is running waiting for the response *********** (906)

**May 27, 2013 11:45:13 AM com.xxx.tocf.test.SocketClientTest ofsmlEnqSimpleTest13
INFO: OFSML 13 Simple Enquiry test is in progress...**

***Another one case is started***

May 27, 2013 11:45:13 AM com.xxx.tocf.test.socket.SocketClient send
INFO: System.currentTimeMillis() : -> 1369635313336 : System.currentTimeMillis()- startTime : -> 0 : timeout -> 5000 : startTime -> 1369635313336 : condition : true
May 27, 2013 11:45:13 AM com.xxx.tocf.test.socket.SocketClient$ResponseReceiver run
INFO: _responses.size() >= _expectedCount : -> false : _responses.size() -> 0 : _expectedCount -> 1

*** Assume there may be chance of different read***

May 27, 2013 11:45:13 AM com.xxx.tocf.test.socket.SocketClient$ResponseReceiver run
**INFO: size captured : 195399**
May 27, 2013 11:45:13 AM com.xxx.tocf.test.socket.SocketClient$ResponseReceiver run
**INFO: size captured : 1195528239**
May 27, 2013 11:45:13 AM com.xxx.tocf.test.socket.SocketClient$ResponseReceiver run
**INFO:  ofsRes Creating with this size : 195399**
May 27, 2013 11:45:13 AM com.xxx.tocf.test.socket.SocketClient$ResponseReceiver run
INFO:  ofsRes Creating with this size : 1195528239
May 27, 2013 11:45:13 AM com.xxx.tocf.test.socket.SocketClient$ResponseReceiver run
INFO:  Buffer Creating with this size : 195399
**Exception in thread "Thread-22" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space**
    at com.xxx.tocf.test.socket.SocketClient$ResponseReceiver.run(SocketClient.java:147)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
May 27, 2013 11:45:13 AM com.xxx.tocf.test.socket.SocketClient$ResponseReceiver run
INFO:  Reading data created Buffer Size : 759
May 27, 2013 11:45:13 AM com.xxx.tocf.test.socket.SocketClient$ResponseReceiver run
INFO:  readSize (readSize += bufferSize): 759
May 27, 2013 11:45:13 AM com.xxx.tocf.test.socket.SocketClient$ResponseReceiver run
INFO:  size (size -= bufferSize): 194640
May 27, 2013 11:45:13 AM com.xxx.tocf.test.socket.SocketClient$ResponseReceiver run
INFO:  Buffer Creating with this size : 194640
May 27, 2013 11:45:13 AM com.xxx.tocf.test.socket.SocketClient$ResponseReceiver run
INFO:  Reading data created Buffer Size : 1533
May 27, 2013 11:45:13 AM com.xxx.tocf.test.socket.SocketClient$ResponseReceiver run
INFO:  readSize (readSize += bufferSize): 2292
May 27, 2013 11:45:13 AM com.xxx.tocf.test.socket.SocketClient$ResponseReceiver run
INFO:  size (size -= bufferSize): 193107
May 27, 2013 11:45:13 AM com.xxx.tocf.test.socket.SocketClient$ResponseReceiver run
INFO:  Buffer Creating with this size : 193107
May 27, 2013 11:45:13 AM com.xxx.tocf.test.socket.SocketClient$ResponseReceiver run
INFO:  Reading data created Buffer Size : 767

Answer (score 0):

> Assume if sender threads waits for particular response from other end.

Why? You already have a receiver thread.

> During that time if any other Testcases (I mean threads) which starts to push their requests and do the execution means, the response receiver thread having the logic of

```
byte[] ofsRes = new byte[size];
```

Where did the value of `size` come from? And what exactly is the meaning of the sender thread and the receiver thread both trying to read the response? I don't know what you expect to happen, but what *will* happen is entirely undefined. This doesn't make any sense. You need to decide who is supposed to read the response, and let them read it. Probably you need to introduce some synchronization between the sender and receiver threads so that the sender doesn't send the next request until the receiver has received the result of the previous one. Better still, get rid of the receiver thread and have the sending thread receive its own responses.

> This part will receive the jVm Out of memory error occurs.

Of course it will. It is getting a basically random value of `size` from somewhere and trying to allocate an amount of memory which is therefore also random.

> I suspect the simultaneous read of response receiver threads causing this issue, allocating more size of byte object in heap.

Right again. The solution is not to do it.

Comment: thanks for your reply. i altered some content here. sorry for my mistake. Sender thread not waiting actually. The size is the variable which captures the data int size = dataInputStream.readInt();.Please give your suggestion!